# Find and replace all matching elements in a 2d list with a value

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list [[1134],[2221],[3321],[2324]].
It is outputted as

```
1 1 3 4
2 2 2 1
3 3 2 1
2 3 2 4
```

The user enters a row(0-3) and column(0-3).
If the user enters row=1 and column=2

```
    1 1 3 4
    2 2(2) 1
    3 3 2 1
    2 3 2 4
```

The program should find all matching values from that point and then replace them with 'x'. Matches can be horizontal or vertical. Must be at least n in a row to match. So the list would look like this:

```
    1 1 3 4
    x x x 1
    3 3 x 1
    2 3 x 4
```

Please help how would I do this.

So far I have tried:

```
def check_matching(row,col,list):
    SIZE=len(list)
    n=3
    upcount =0
    downcount =0
    leftcount =0
    rightcount =0
    
    #Up Match
    if row-n>=-1:
        upcount-=1
        for i in range(row, -1, -1):
            #print(list[i][col])
            if list[i][col] == list[row][col]:
                upcount+=1

    

    #Down Match
    if row+n<=SIZE:
        downcount-=1
        for i in range(row, SIZE):
            #print(list[i][col])
            if(list[i][col] == list[row][col]):
                downcount+= 1

    

    #Left Match up
    if col-n>=-1:
        leftcount-=1
        for i in range(col, -1, -1):
            #print(list[row][i])
            if(list[row][i] == list[row][col]):
                leftcount+=1

    
        
            
    #Right Match
    if col+n<=SIZE:
        rightcount-=1
        for i in range(col, SIZE):
            #print(list[row][i])
            if(list[row][i] == list[row][col]):
                rightcount+=1
        
    if upcount>=n-1 or downcount>=n-1 or leftcount>=n-1 or rightcount>=n-1:
        print ("match")

    if upcount>=n-1:
        for i in range(col, -1, -1):
            #print(list[row][i])
            if(list[row][i] == list[row][col]):
                list[row][i]='.'
```

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Can you give an example on what you would like it to return? Should it return a new list?

Comment: It should just edit the original list. So replace the "2"s with "x"s

Answer (score 0):

I made a totally different version of your code and that's what I got:

```py
def check_matching(row, col, arr):
    value = arr[row][col]
    for i, rows in enumerate(arr):
        for j, cols in enumerate(rows):
            if cols == value and (i == row or j == col):
                arr[i][j] = "x"
    return arr
    
print(check_matching(1, 2, [[1, 1, 3, 4],[2, 2, 2, 1],[3, 3, 2, 1],[2, 3, 2, 4]]))
```

The output will be a matrix with this format:

```
    [[1,  1,  3,  4],
    ['x','x','x', 1],
    [ 3,  3, 'x', 1],
    [ 2,  3, 'x', 4]]
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly

Comment: sadly this didnt work. It doesnt change anything to the list.

Comment: Doesn't it return a new list with the output that you want?

Comment: sadly it doesnt change the list at all. Im not sure why.

Comment: It doesn't change the list, but it returns a new one. So you can type `oldlist = check_matching(param1, param2, param3)` and you will have what you want

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much. Is there anyway you could code it so it would only change values that are in a row. As of now when you give it a value it changes every value in the row or column that matches. But I need it to only do that for values that are in a row horizontally or vertically